# Can you join these two independent clauses without using that?

Tags: sentence-construction

"I was so sad everything went wrong."

Is this a run-on sentence?

This sentence has two subjects ( *I* and *everything*) and two verbs (*was* and *went*).  There are two independent clauses.  There is no punctuation between them.  At first glance I said it was run-on sentence and the word *that* should be inserted between *sad* and *everything*, but then a student asked me why it was necessary to insert *that*?

Comment: The sentence itself looks lacking something. *I was so sad **as** everything went wrong; I was so sad, everything went wrong; I was so sad because everything went wrong.* and so on!

Comment: That **could** be inserted between the two clauses but it is optional and  often omitted in informal speech. See for example [omitting that in two-word conjunctions](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv336.shtml).

Comment: And the two-word conjunctions scenario is just one of the circumstances where `that` will be omitted in informal speech. *I'm glad you asked this question.*

Answer (score 1):

If the clauses actually are independent (so that the sentence is equal in meaning to "I was so sad. Everything went wrong.", with no obvious causal relationship between one and the other - somebody was sad, and also everything went wrong), then yes, it's a run-on sentence.

However, it seems that the clauses are not independent, and there's a causal relationship between them ("I was sad that/because everything went wrong"), and in this case, as @Laure says in the comment, "that" could be ommited.

It isn't always the case that two clauses with different subjects and verbs are independent. Compare "I told him (that) he was being silly".